# Sort articles alphabetically

Tags: google-reader

I have a feed in Google Reader with about 500 unread articles in it over the last four months (probably 100 read ones are interspersed in there too). I need to be able to sort them alphabetically by title, but Google only offers chronological sorting options.

I'm fine with using external applications (an offline reader?), manual processes (export to .csv?), whatever.  All I require is:

A) the title
B) the link
C) able to sort alphabetically by the title
D) only the unread items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the right top corner click "settings". Then click "Reader settings". Open "Folders and Tags" tab. All of them are default private. Click "private" next to the one that you want and set it as "public". click "view public page". On that page there is a link labeled "Atom feed". Click it (do it i  Firefox because Chrome by default don't try to subscribe). Firefox asks you with which program would you want to subscribe to that feed. Choose Outlook if you have (or another RSS/atom subscriber tool). Than you can sort it as you wish by which column you want.

Comment: Thanks spinodal.  The atom feed actually crashes my Firefox, but I can open in IE, save, and open the XML file in Excel (didn't even know that was possible until now).